# Modular Database, Inheritance of Schema

Tags: database-design, inheritance

Consider multiple relational database schemas that have an inheritance dependency structure as known from OOP systems:

[image: layers]

Tables are just a placeholder for arbitrary database objects such as Views, Stored Procedures, etc.

Are there any methods or tools that might help me express this abstraction? Such as a package manager that builds modular create and upgrade scripts?

(I am not talking of O/R Mapping *within* one database schema. Actually I am primarily thinking about an BI application, so there is no ORM anyway.)

Comment: Are you trying to develop a multi tenant system?  (multiple clients using basically the same app but with the possibility of some customization?)

Comment: No, this is not required. Consider thousands of database instances/installations

Comment: I am still not quite sure what you are trying to accomplish.  From the diagram it looks like a software as a service platform with multiple clients and possible customization per client.

Comment: I understand "multi tenant system" as multiple clients in one hosting environment, maybe I am wrong here. What I am trying to achieve is a clean versioning at each level. Liquibase looks interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps Liquibase can help with its include tag. Put the more common table definitions in separate changesets. Then include these in the more specific ones.

This allows you to maintain the different levels of tables separately, but generate specific databases as required. Plus it adds all the versioning options of Liquibase.

For more information see the [documentation](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/include.html) of the Liquibase include tag.